# Symfony2 - @internal and @see annotations

Tags: symfony, annotations

I'm working on an existing project, and can't find information about `@see` and `@internal` annotations, used in this project. Do anyone know where I can find such information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These annotations are not part of any Symfony2 component. There is an application called `phpDoc` that uses this to generate HTML-Documentations.

See the [@see](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) and [@internal](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html) sections of their manual.

Basically these annotations don't influence your application at all.

Comment: This is new for me. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like they've changed their URL structures - now see [@see](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) and [@internal](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a custom annotation. It is [phpDoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/)